# How can I make a list in Python like (0,6,12, .. 144)?

Tags: python, list

I am not sure, whether I should use for -loop. Perhaps, like

```
for i in range(145): 
  by 6:    //mistake here?
  print i
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
for i in range(0,150,6):
     print i
```

if you are stepping by a constant

Comment: This is better to read than Ramponi's answer, in my opinion.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Oh, damn it. You know, the fastest gun in the west thing :) +1

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer:

```
for i in xrange(25):    # from 0 to 24
    print 6*i
```

You can easily build a list containing the same numbers with a similar construct named *list comprehension*:

```
numbers = [6*i for i in xrange(25)]
print numbers
```

If you already have a list of (unknown) numbers, say `someNumbers`, but you want to print only those which are multiples of 6:

```
for i in someNumbers:
    if i%6 == 0:
        print i
```

Comment: So far i've never used xrange and looked it up just now. +1 for enlightenment

Answer (score -2):

reqlist  = [i for i in range(0,150,6)]

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. Well the answer is a little short but it has a nice list comprehension and it solves the problem

Answer (score -5):

```
i = 1

while i * 6 < 144:
    i = i + 1
    print i * 6
```

There are plenty of ways to do this